# How to get Coordinates or Position of a figure(line) into a canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a Canvas which include a figure (ex. a Table). How can i get the coordinates of a line into this Table? or the x-coord and y-coord of the first top Line of the Table?

```
 _________________________ <- this line   
|                         |
 _________________________
|                         |
 _________________________
```

for example : http://jsfiddle.net/trouble/CVjwj/

Thanks

Comment: The question lacks details. How to you draw your <canvas>?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa http://jsfiddle.net/trouble/CVjwj/

Comment: Still do not clear what your problem is you have set the x and y coordinates of the top of the table to be from (20,20) to (20,100)

Comment: @jing3142 that's right! but how someone else (not me who has programme it) can get this coordinates programmatically!

Answer (score 0):

To the browser, once something is drawn on a canvas, the browser has as much information as if it were an `<img>` tag.  The browser doesn't know about lines in the same way it does with a CSS border or an SVG element.  You would have to use image recognition concepts to find the borders, which I would not recommend.

The proper way to convey information about the canvas, and the way that will give you the least headaches, is to provide both the canvas and details about it to the programmer.  Something like, "Here's a canvas, and I drew lines, here, here, and here."

For example, you could have a JavaScript object:

```
var table = {
    canvas: myCanvasElement,
    rows: [
        {
            cells: [
                {
                    x: 25,
                    y: 25
                    w: 100
                    h: 50
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Ideally, you would generate this object as you are drawing on the canvas.

*If* you want to do it the hard way, you can technically read one pixel at a time and evaluate if it is black or white (assuming you don't have blurry lines), but your programmer will still need to know where to start checking.  This is much more computationally expensive, harder to program for, and more brittle if you decide to make a change to your drawing.  **Think of the canvas as a output, not an input.**